# Can I say the word LEGO in my book

Tags: copyright, story

Can I say the *lego set was destroyed* on perpouse by someone?

Comment: Note that it's officially [written in all caps](https://twitter.com/LEGO_Group/status/842423564829618177?lang=en).

Comment: Lego, lEgo, leGo … LEGO, legol … egol, … LEGO EGO, … etc. are all considered the same. Why? Because it‘s easy to mix them up, e.g. during a business phone call, on a bad fax-copy etc. Those variations aren’t protected BUT can be puzzled with the protected one. So to avoid trouble just don‘t use trademarks WITHOUT permission. The trademarks owner has to protect its trademark to keep it alive. E.g. Apple is known to e.g. sue bars, Kindergardens etc. which use names which remotely sound like Apple-trademarks. So just don‘t even consider it.

Comment: ... And check your spelling!!